# Unit/Performance Testing GWT Application with Server

Tags: gwt, testing

There is a ton of resources out there for testing GWT applications, but I'm struggling finding clear and current answers for my specific situation.

My application relies heavily on server interaction via JSON requests. Typically when I run my client side GWT program in Dev mode from within eclipse the launch configuration uses my specified server and doesn't launch it's own and everything works as expected.

I'm trying to test using GWTTestCase. However when I run the Google-JUnit launch configuration, it launches its own server and my tests fails since its using the wrong host. Is there a way to specify which server the test uses? Or am I going about testing this in the wrong way?

Comment: The wrong host? You need to elaborate on what this means.

Comment: The test case is launching the app from within its own server instance rather than deploying to an existing server. So its using an ip address and port of something like 192.168.1.1:98609 when the client code expects the app be running within a different server instance which can provide JSON responses. In this case the host and port should be localhost:8182.

Comment: You should not hard code port numbers or ip addresses in your application. The unit test is operating correctly, as designed.

Comment: I think I'm not conveying the actual problem correctly, so I apologize. The host/port is not hardcoded, it uses the host/port of the running app to make its JSON GET request. Under normal circumstances this works correctly since the server serving the content is the same server the client module is running on. In the case of running the unit test however, it has deployed a standalone server which does not have the JSON-serving code on it.

Comment: During a GWTTestCase unit test, you should never contact any external server. You should only contact the server that is spun up during testing.

Comment: I guess that is the crux of the problem. Is there no way to use an external server to deploy to rather than the default Jetty one that is launched on test launch?

Comment: It's possible, but it's wrong. If you rely on an external server that you have control over, that server should employ its own unit tests. If you have no control, you should write integration tests that would not use `GWTTestCase`.

Comment: I have control over the server, partially. The server is not GWT, and I'm more interested in testing what the client does with the results from the server than how the server handles the requests. If GWTTestCase is not the way to go, is there something else you would suggest? Is Selenium the way to go?